# JenkinsX - how to install apps

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

jx has commands:

```
  get applications Display one or more Applications and their versions
  get apps       Display one or more installed Apps
```

I have imported some projects and they are building fine. I can see them when I call `jx get applications`:

```
APPLICATION          INTEGRATION PODS URL
integration-backend  123208      2/2  
integration-frontend 90          2/2
```

however `jx get apps` returns:

```
No Apps found
```

How do we actually install apps? It's really hard to find any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need better docs for sure - there's details here: https://jenkins-x.io/apps/

you can add apps via [jx add app](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_add_app/) e.g. like the [Jenkins App](https://jenkins-x.io/architecture/custom-jenkins/)

Comment: so apps are kind of features for jenkins-x itself and applications are projects build with pipelines?